Uniqueness of the Taylor polynomial of a function
I'm in trouble understanding this theorem:

For a given function, differentiable n times at a given point $x_0$, there exist a unique polynomial $P_n$ (of degree $\le$n) such that
$$\forall \; k=0,...,n \quad f^{(k)}(x_0)=P^{(k)}(x_0)$$

I understand the "existence" part of the theorem: in fact it is possible to build a polynomial that respects this condition by picking up a generic one, write it in powers of $(x-x_0)$
$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{P^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}\cdot(x-x_0)^k$$
and then assume that $P^{(k)}(x_0)$ must be equal to $f^{(k)}(x_0)$ for every $k=0,...,n$, and this takes us to
$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}\cdot(x-x_0)^k$$
However, I can't understand if this is enough to demonstrate uniqueness (and possibly why) or what is missing to demonstrate it. Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english.

The usual notation for evaluate a function is $f(x)$, not $f_{(x)}$. That's one of the most standard notation in Mathematics, why would you change it?

Actually, you are asking the wrong question.  You have assumed existence of the polynomial, and have then shown that there is only one possibility for its coefficients, and therefore only one possible polynomial.  In other words, you have proved uniqueness!  Are you certain that you fully understand the existence part?

@jjagmath I didn't aim to change notation, I'm simply used to writing the x at the bottom when I write my notes.

Uniqueness just means that if you take a polynomial with those properties, then it's equal to the Taylor polynomial. This is also exactly what you have shown

@David thank you
